# Is the Entertainment Weekly article real?

Tags: historical-accuracy, the-great-buck-howard

The titular character in *The Great Buck Howard* (2008) is based on [The Amazing Kreskin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kreskin). In a pivotal moment in the story, Buck Howard passes out after discovering he had been mocked in the pages of Entertainment Weekly. Is this based on an actual article about the actual Kreskin? Can this article even be found online?